# How can I use my command line as an output for my ruby program on notepad++

Tags: ruby, command-line, notepad++

How can I use my command line as an output for my ruby program on notepad++?

I have tried following multiple tutorials, the most straight forward being: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9hrI9ve9ng

Whenever I try, however, I receive this error on the command line:

```
cmpe131hw1.rb:1:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - widgets.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
```

[(The notepad++ file is on my desktop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4vKq.png)

I have looked up the error but my searches always take me to people discussing how to read in a text file in ruby from the command line. I have been able to program directly from the command line, including reading files, so their threads do not directly match what my problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Don't use a link to show the error; Instead, copy/paste the error into your question where we can easily copy it and use it for searches if necessary. What have you tried? Why didn't those work?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your `cmpe131hw1.rb`.  It looks like a file that it is looking for on the first line does not exist.

Comment: You were right! I was wondering why I was getting an error that, when searching online, was taking me to people with file reading problems. What happened was that the very first thing in my code was reading a file which was not located in the desktop. Then my program would stop there or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is running in the command line. The problem is the code within the file. It is having trouble finding/reading the csv file you are asking it to open. Maybe you can add the contents of the rb file to this question?

Comment: This is not an answer. This should have been written as a comment on the question. You have a reputation of over 50 so you can add comments.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting all sorts of different approaches from the command line, the problem was in fact coming from the program file I was trying to run. I opened a new .rb file and ran a simple

```
puts "Hello World"
```

and was able to get an output through the method shown in the video link. I should have done this from the start, but I was frantically trying to see if my programming homework would output correctly.